# "unexpected $ after $$" and "unclosed $$ found at $" errors with inline math inside display mode

Tags: macros, errors, optional-arguments, arguments, displaystyle

I am trying to define a new command for different types of homomorphisms. The command is:

```
\newcommand{\Hom}[2][]{%
    \operatorname{Hom}_{\textnormal{#1}}\left({#2}\right)%
    }
```

The outputs of this command in inline and display mode, when no optional argument is given, are correct. For example this is the output for `$\Hom{A,B}$` and `$$\Hom{A,B}$$`

[image: Hom(A,B)]

Then there could be an additional subscript to specify which type of homomorphisms I'm referring to. For example, `$\Hom[gr]{G,H}$` or `$$\Hom[gr]{G,H}$$` both have a "correct" output (*I have still a problem with spacing between operator and first parethesis*)

[image: Hom_gr(G,H)]

Finally, if I have to include some inline math in the subscript, LaTex gives me contrary error tags in displaymode. For instance, if I try to compile `$\Hom[$k$-alg]{A,B}$`, no errors in sight, but the same command in display mode, `$$\Hom[$k$-alg]{A,B}$$`, give both error and no-error. Let me explain: I receive the output (*and some could argue why I'm here  wainig*) but at the same time there's an error allert, as in the next pictures, but no error message in the "Logs and output files".

Output

[image: Hom_k-alg(A,B)]

Errors:

"unexpected $ after $$"

"unclosed $$ found at $"

[image: errors next to line]

Is there a solution to this problem, or I just accept the error tag, and ignore it? If there's somthing I can do, I'm willing to try every advice.

**Note 1:** I am aware of the debate about using `$$...$$` and `\[...\]`, but I'm willing to use this new command in some already written LaTeX documents in which I've used `$...$` and `$$...$$`, and I'd like to mantain consistency.

**Note 2:** Sorry for the pictures dimensions, I'm new in this of asking a question and I don't know all settings.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Regarding the side issue, *viz*., "I have still a problem with spacing between operator and first parethesis": That's because the code uses `\left` (and `\right`) even when it's absolutely not needed and, in fact, can be rather counterproductive.

Comment: I receive neither error alerts nor warning messages when I run `$$\Hom[$k$-alg]{A,B}$$` or, better yet, `\[ \Hom[$k$-alg]{A,B} \]`. I run MacTeX2023 with TeXworks as the editor; which system do you employ?

Comment: Is that the Overleaf IDE?  The left side tries to analyze your source code, but can get confused when you do weird things like embed `$...$` within `$$...$$`.  What really matters is if you have a red number above your pdf.

Comment: @mico I'm using the overleaf compiler, and as stated by @teepeemm, it's just a problem with the inside working of this compiler. I was worried for nothing. Regarding the parenthesis, my example was not oriented to show that, I might open another question explaining why I was using `\left(` and `\right)`.

Comment: @Teepeemm thank you for your comment. No red numbers above my pdf, I understand now it's only a "problem" of overleaf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are not errors, but just wrong advice from Overleaf that is sometimes unable to comply with nested math formulas.

It probably wouldn't balk if you write explicitly `[\textnormal{$k$-alg}]` as the optional argument, but isn't able to guess that the arguments is passed to `\textnormal`.

So, ignore those messages.

There are other important things about your code:

1. `\left` and `\right` should be omitted;
2. the subscript will produce an unwanted space when missing;
3. `$$` should ***never*** be used in a LaTeX `document` environment.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Hom}{o}{%
  \operatorname{Hom}\IfValueT{#1}{_{\textnormal{#1}}}%
}

\newcommand{\lorenzoHom}[2][]{%
    \operatorname{Hom}_{\textnormal{#1}}\left({#2}\right)%
    }

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{My definition}

\begin{gather*}
\Hom(A,B) \\
\Hom[$k$-alg](A,B)
\end{gather*}

\subsubsection*{Your definition}

\begin{gather*}
\lorenzoHom{A,B} \\
\lorenzoHom[$k$-alg]{A,B}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

I don't think there's a gain in using braces `{}` around `A,B` just in order to get parentheses: it's more natural to input `(A,B)` directly.

[image]

Can you see the unwanted spaces?

Comment: thank you for your answer! I have explained why I was using `\left(` and `\right)` in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/713231/adaptive-parentheses-in-the-definition-of-a-command-how-to-avoid-odd-space), to be more clear, if you'd like to have a look.