# Adaptive parentheses in the definition of a command: how to avoid odd space

Tags: macros, spacing, brackets

I'm trying to improve a command with adaptive parentheses, but I don't know how to avoid an unexpected blank space between the operator and the first parenthesis.

I already had a problem with this command in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/707534/unexpected-after-and-unclosed-found-at-errors-with-inline-math-ins), and I wanted to state exactly what this command is supposed to do.

The purpose of this command is to ease the typing process of different types of homomorphisms, and possibly to be generalized for other operators. The original idea was to have a command `\Hom[<subscript>]{<object A>,<object B>}`, which could be used to give the following outputs:
[image: Three examples of usage of this command]
without worrying about the text mode for the subscript, or the operator-name style of `Hom`.
The code for this output normally would be:

```
\operatorname{Hom}_{k}(E,E')
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_X\text{-mod}}(\mathcal{N},\mathcal{M})
\operatorname{Hom}_{A\text{-alg.}}(B,B\otimes_A C)
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/707562/290959), I have no further problems with the subscript of the operator, but I still want to have adaptive parentheses. In my question, I didn't explain why I was interested in this feature, which wasn't obvious at first glance.

Normally the two objects whose homomorphisms I'm referring to are simple, but sometimes they are products, sums, unions, intersections, etc. which need bigger parentheses to be contained.

My solution in the first place was to use `\left(` and `\right)`, but the output would result in the operator oddly spaced from the parenthesis. The easy solution could be to use `\bigl(`/`\bigr)` and their variations, writing something like `\Hom[<subscript>]\bigl(\prod A_i, B\bigr)`, but I would like to not have to adjust the dimensions case-by-case.

In this picture, I hope I've made clear the reason why adaptive parentheses are needed and how the spacing changes with different coding. The last line shows the output choosing the dimension of the parentheses.
[image: Parenthesis variations]

This is the MWE of the command: my first version and the version from the answer I already cited

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% First try, with subscript space problems
\newcommand{\firstHom}[2][]{%
    \operatorname{Hom}_{\textnormal{#1}}\left({#2}\right)%
    }

% Command from @egreg answer, without parentheses
\NewDocumentCommand{\answerHom}{o}{%
  \operatorname{Hom}\IfValueT{#1}{_{\textnormal{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{First definition}

\begin{align*}
&\firstHom{A,B} &&
\firstHom[\(k\)-alg]{A,B} &&
\firstHom[\(k\)-alg]{A,\prod_{i\in I}B_i}
\end{align*}

\subsubsection*{Answer definition}

\begin{align*}
&\answerHom(A,B) &&
\answerHom[\(k\)-alg](A,B) &&
\answerHom[\(k\)-alg](A,\prod_{i\in I}B_i)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Is there a solution to this problem, maybe not too complicated?

Comment: Can you use math that is not too complicated to demonstrate the problem? :)

Comment: @yannisl Sorry I don't understand what you mean, could you explain further, please? If it is about understanding what those homomorphisms mean, they are just real examples to show how would a big operator work, I could have typed just a general `\Hom[sub]{\prod k,k}` to show why the parentheses need to adapt. I just wanted to show how changes the space between the operator with its subscript `Hom_sub` and the first parenthesis `(...` when using `\left(` and `\right)`.

Comment: I believe the [`mleftright`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mleftright) package does what you are looking for. However, personally, I would recommend manually setting the sizes as, even with the correct spacing, the automatic parentheses are often too large for a visually pleasing result (as can actually be seen in your example; smaller parentheses would be nicer).

Comment: Not only there's odd spacing, but also too big fences.

Answer (score 1):

The spacing issue is addressed by the [`mleftright`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mleftright) package. However, using automatically scaled parentheses rarely yields satisfactory results. It is better to choose the best size yourself.

Here's a possible implementation. The helper macro `\scaled@delimiter@expression` is a bit overkill here, but I had it on hand and it does the job nicely.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

% If you really want to use \left and \right:
\usepackage{mleftright}

\makeatletter
  % A command for typesetting expressions with (possibly scaled) delimiters.
  % Use as follows: \scaled@delimiter@expression[<scale>]{<left_delimiter>}{<middle_delimiter>}{<right_delimiter>}{<expression>}
  % Input \auto for auto-scaling, . for obsolete delimiters.
  % In the <expression>, type \<pos>@dlmtr where the delimiters belong (<pos> being left, middle or right).
  \NewDocumentCommand\scaled@delimiter@expression{o m m m m}{\begingroup
    \def\@auto##1{\middle##1\let\auto\@auto}%
    \def\left@dlmtr{\let\auto\mleft\ifx\auto#1\relax\else\mathopen\fi\IfValueT{#1}{#1}#2\let\auto\@auto}%
    \def\right@dlmtr{\let\auto\mright\ifx\auto#1\relax\else\mathclose\fi\IfValueT{#1}{#1}#4}%
    \def\middle@dlmtr{\IfValueT{#1}{#1}#3}%
    #5
  \endgroup}
  \NewDocumentCommand\Hom{e_ o m}{%
    \scaled@delimiter@expression[#2]{(}{.}{)}{\operatorname{Hom}\IfValueT{#1}{_{#1}}\left@dlmtr#3\right@dlmtr}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
  \Hom{A, B} \\
  \Hom[\Big]{A, B} \\
  \Hom_{\text{\(k\)-alg}}{A, B} \\
  \Hom_{\text{\(k\)-alg}}[\Big]{\prod_{i \in I} A_i, \prod_{i \in I} B_i} \\
  \intertext{and if you really want to}
  \Hom_{\text{\(k\)-alg}}[\auto]{\prod_{i \in I} A_i, \prod_{i \in I} B_i}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

However, I find the obscurity of the markup not to be worth the added benefit here. The braces are basically replaced by parentheses, so directly typing parentheses is clearer. The unusual embellishment argument isn't ideal either, though other argument types have their own shortcomings in this case. All in all, `\Hom` looks like an operator, so it's best to just use an operator.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

% If you really want to use \left and \right:
\usepackage{mleftright}
\mleftright

\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
  \Hom(A, B) \\
  \Hom\Bigl( A, B \Bigr) \\
  \Hom_{\text{\(k\)-alg}}(A, B) \\
  \Hom_{\text{\(k\)-alg}}\Bigl( \prod_{i \in I} A_i, \prod_{i \in I} B_i \Bigr) \\
  \intertext{and if you really want to}
  \Hom_{\text{\(k\)-alg}}\left( \prod_{i \in I} A_i, \prod_{i \in I} B_i \right)
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Both of the MWEs above give identical output.
[image: MWE output]